# Why is this Google + basic sharing not working?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, sharing

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener( 

        new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick (View v) {
                // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
                Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
                    .setType("text/plain")
                    .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
                    .getIntent();

                startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I'm getting an Error on the "OnClickListener" and the "(View V)", also I am near a complete beginnner to Java and Android trying to add some basic Google plus sharing so please help me out

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv1rxec13p5zlt5/Picture1.png?dl=0

Comment: I think you should use  `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: How would i do that can you please give me an example please

Comment: Replace `OnClickListener` with `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: Now . Setonclicklistener is red

Comment: underlined red or completely red? Also, which error does Android Studio show?

Comment: Completly red alot of errors such as

Comment: Error expected (,; illegal start etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call methods inside the class block, you have to do it in a method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                //your code
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Now PlusShare is red

Comment: PlusShare is not part of the Android SDK. I expected it would come from  a library you referenced. Where does that codesnippet come from?

Comment: It comes from the Google plus developers page

Comment: Then add their library as gradle dependency.